# Google Docs Cursor Effect

Tags: ajax

How does Google allow other people to see other people's cursors?  Live edit is one thing, but how is the cursor effect achieved?  Or how could it have be achieved?

EDIT:
Not only the cursor, but also the highlight effect?

Comment: is this a dead question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Docs uses Operational Transformation, here is a demo: http://ot.substance.io/demo/
And here is an visual explanation about how it works: http://ot.substance.io/visualization/

The cursors (carets) are simple DIV elements made to blink, and each has a position in the document:

```
{ line: 3, char: 41 }
```

Pressing the Right Arrow key will move the cursor at position: `{ line: 3, char: 42 }`

A selection is a range (from -> to):

```
{ from: { line: 3, char: 41 }, to: { line: 4, char: 29 } }
```